# asp.net listview select item without databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a listview in my asp.net page that binds to a datatable, which is done the the page load from the code behind.  I am trying to use the SelectedItemTemplate, but from trial and error, I can only get this to work if the control is databound after the postback.  This works fine, but the problem is that is means a call back the database each time, even though no data  has changed, which make the user experience slow.  My question therefore is: is it possible to select and an item on a listview, display the SelectedItemTemplate, without having to do a full rebinding of the data.  I don't mind doing a postback to the server, I just want to avoid making unneccessay calls to the DB.  Here is my markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" EnablePersistedSelection="True">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="Div1" runat="server">
            <!-- My Item Controls -->
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <div id="Div2" runat="server">
            <!-- My Selected Item Controls -->
        </div>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And here is my codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Not IsPostBack Then
      'Load the data on the first page load  
      LoadEvents()
   End If
End Sub

Protected Sub LoadEvents()
    'Some code to get data from DB and bind to listview control
End Sub

Protected Sub lv_SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As ListViewSelectEventArgs) Handles lv.SelectedIndexChanging
    lv.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex
    LoadEvents()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the `DataTable` in `Session` and retrieve it in `LoadEvents`. Only while loading initially, it will come from DataBase. The  `LoadEvents` sub may look like this:

```
Private Sub LoadEvents(Optional ByVal refresh As Boolean = False)
    Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable
    If refresh = True Then
        'Code to get data from database
        'and fill myTable Goes here
        ' ... ... ...

        Session("MyTable") = myTable
    Else
        If Not Session("MyTable") Is Nothing Then
            myTable = DirectCast(Session("MyTable"), DataTable)
        End If
    End If

    lv.DataSource = myTable
    lv.DataBind()
End Sub
```

When it is called without parameter, it will get data from Session. In `Page_Load` we need to call it with `true` to get fresh data from DataBase:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     If Not IsPostBack Then
          'Load the data on the first page load 
          'Called the sub with parameter to get fresh data from db 
          LoadEvents(true)
     End If
 End Sub
```